# Need to print the max element column in java

Tags: java

Hello I am new in java and I want to write a program where I will print the max element from the column in 2D table. I am updating a picture to show what actually I want to print.
[image]

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MaxColumnElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int col = sc.nextInt();
        int row = sc.nextInt();

        int[][] table = new int [col][row];
        int max= 0;
       for(int i=0; i<col; i++){


            for(int j=0; j<row; j++){
                max= table[i][0];
                table[i][j]= sc.nextInt();

                if(max<table[i][j]){

                    max= table[i][j];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Maximum number is "+ max);
            System.out.println();
        } 

    }   
}
```

Comment: You never insert values to `table`. By the way you are mixing `col` and `row`, it's `int[row][col]`

Comment: Thanks,I changed them now and it is printing now 10,5 and - 3.But it prints before I input the last row [4, 2 ,-6 ,9] and isn't printing from the last column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index a matrix (2D table) like this:

> matrix[**row**][**column**]

where **row** and **column** are 0-based indexes.

You have to change the loop like this:

```
int max= 0;
    for(int i=0; i<col; i++){
        // select first element of a column as temp max
        max= table[0][i];
        for(int j=0; j<row; j++){
            // cycle on rows
            if(max<table[j][i]){
                max= table[j][i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum number is "+ max);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

1. You have to cycle on column. Select the first element of a column as temporary maximum
2. You have to init the max when you end a row, not inside the nested loop

---

Side note: I suggest you to keep the code clean (because is a simple example and I assume you have a little file) and separate tasks:

1. First, read the file (perhaps print the file content to be sure the content it's ok)
2. Then, check the maximum of each column

In this way will be simpler for you to catch problems.

Comment: @user12741421 add the link of the new question here :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the values insertion and finding the maximum value so you can iterate the array by columns

```
public class MaxColumnElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int col = sc.nextInt();
        int row = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                table[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        int[][] table = new int[col][row];
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
            int max = table[0][i];
            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
                if (max < table[j][i]) {
                    max = table[j][i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Maximum number is " + max);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Maximum number is 10
Maximum number is 5
Maximum number is -3
Maximum number is 9
```